# Website stopped working (503) after adding .NET Standard 2.0 project to the solution

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-standard-2.0

**Problem**

The website builds and runs no problem on localhost. The website builds and deploys from Azure DevOps to a local on-premise server no problem as well. When you try to access the website on the server though; it crashes the application pool to the point it turns itself off and returns 503 afterward. This is after trying to add a .NET Standard 2.0 project to a recently upgraded .NET Framework 4.8 website.

**Recent Changes Overview**

- Recently upgraded from `.NET Framework 4.5.2` to `.NET Framework 4.8`. Website worked fine after deployment.
- Created a `.NET Standard 2.0` project inside the solution, moved many classes to it, and had the `.NET Framework 4.8` website reference it. After this change is when the application pool began crashing.

The intention with the `.NET Standard 2.0` project is to have a `.NET Framework 4.8` and `.NET 6` website/api running parallel next to each other so I can slowly migrate functionality bit-by-bit while using the `.NET Standard 2.0` library project as a basis for both.

**What I've Tried**

- Checked the IIS logs. They only state there was a 503 returned. Nothing helpful.
- Checked failed request trace logs. Nothing in there.
- Event log has application event logs for the crashes (see below).
- Reinstalled .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 6 (ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle) on the target server.

**Application Event Log**

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215df96
Faulting module name: PerfMon64.dll, version: 8.0.11057.0, time stamp: 0x5f65478b
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000000000013f68f
Faulting process id: 0x1370
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8e239d2a9099e
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Monitoring Agent\Agent\APMDOTNETAgent\V8.0.10918.0\PerfMon64.dll
Report Id: 1f0f8b78-4e2d-11ed-8119-005056a40b02
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Searching the Exception Code and Fault Offset lead me to something about the Monitoring Service and SCOM, but I tried turning off the Monitoring service and I don't think SCOM is installed at all. Not sure how to troubleshoot from here.

**Questions**

Any assistance in even knowing how to troubleshoot this further would be greatly appreciated. I suspect the issue is package or dependency related; but I can't even get a useful error message from the server so I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Do you need to install a runtime for .NET Standard 2.0? I can't seem to find anything when searching if so.

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Monitoring Agent\Agent\APMDOTNETAgent\V8.0.10918.0\PerfMon64.dll` is part of SCOM, so its appearing in the crash log indicates SCOM is there on this machine. When you said "I tried turning off the Monitoring service" what did you change exactly? Did that stop IIS crash?

Comment: This is a very generic error, there is no specific cause for this. so you can try to debug the cause using IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool, this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: @LexLi I disabled and stopped the service, it did not change anything.
@samwu I've got that setup now, the dumps are 1,500 lines so I'm not sure how to know what is relevant. Searching for "Exception"  a `Exception 0X04242420` is thrown after `aspnet_filter.dll` and `webengine.dll` are mentioned. The only other exception mentioned after that is `Exception 0XE06D7363` following something about Microsoft Monitoring Agent's `Messages64.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

I used the [Debug Diagnostics Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210) as suggested and found some exceptions that made no sense, but pointed to Microsoft Monitoring Service to be the problem.

I uninstalled it and afterwards the exceptions pointed to `System.Globalization`. I installed the NuGet package `System.Globalization` to the project and redeployed and after a recycling the application pool the website began working again.

I'm not sure if uninstalling Microsoft Monitoring Service was necessary in solving the problem, but it was necessary in finding the real exception. I think it was throwing an exception because the actual exception had to do with missing culture, so I assume it somehow causing problems for the monitoring service too (just a guess though).

Comment: "I disabled and stopped the service" is useless, as `PerfMon64.dll` isn't injected into IIS worker process by the SCOM service, but several settings it added to IIS configuration. That's why by uninstalling SCOM (and those settings from IIS) you get rid of that dll injection.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I was very much out of my element with this issue, but I've learned how to at least get an exception message from IIS now and was able to figure some stuff out eventually. I appreciate the explanation/clarification!